# What is the CSS order for a field being hovered and focused

Tags: css, input

What color will my input be when it is focused AND hovered?

```
input:hover {
  color: red;
}

input:focus {
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: add `!important` to one of them to be sure :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are presumably in the same stylesheet and they have the same specificity (one pseudo-class and one element), so the only remaining step in the cascade order is order specified.  That is to say that if it is hovered and focused, it will be blue.

On Specificity: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity

Answer (score 3):

```css
input:hover {
  color: red;
}

input:focus {
  color: blue;
}
```

In the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Awe4T/2/), because the input is focused and the CSS has `:focus` listed last, the input will be blue.

If you [reverse those two rule sets](http://jsfiddle.net/Awe4T/3/), the input will be red, because `:hover` is last.

Answer (score 0):

Try input:focus:hover

Normaly we just have 3 states, active, hover and focus. What you want wont be possible, but try the code above.

Comment: it can actually be more for inputs ([type]). the first is : input{} (sort of unknown state  or any state if stand alone rule :) )